# Casting and dynamic vs static type in Java

Tags: java, casting

I'm learning about static vs dynamic types, and I am to the point of understanding it for the most part, but this case still eludes me.

If class `B` extends `A`, and I have:

```
A x = new B();
```

Is the following allowed?:

```
B y = x;
```

Or is explicit casting required?:

```
B y = (B) x;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Explicit casting is *required*, and will *succeed*.

The reason why it's required is because it doesn't *always* succeed: a variable declared as `A x` can refer to instances that aren't `instanceof B`.

```
// Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String
Object o = "Ha!";
String s = o; // DOESN'T COMPILE

// Compiles fine, cast succeeds at run-time
Object o = "Ha!";
String s = (String) o;

// Compiles fine, throws ClassCastException at run-time
Object o = Boolean.FALSE;
String s = (String) o;
```

Whether or not a cast is required is determined *only* by the declared types of the variables involved, *NOT* by the types of the objects that they are referring to at run-time. This is true even if the references can be resolved at compile-time.

```
final Object o = "Ha!";
String s = o; // STILL doesn't compile!!!
```

Here, even though the `final` variable `o` will always refer to an `instanceof String`, its declared type is still `Object`, and therefore an explicit `(String)` cast is *still* required to compile.