# Why can't I assign an object as shown?

Tags: java, object, equals

I am kinda new in java. I'm reading a chapter in a book about Comparable and Comparator interfaces. With the code beneath, it says *"Find a way to modify that last line of code to make it work"*. Currently, it doesn't compile. What should be done with the last line ?

```
Hello Friend= new Hello("LOL");
Object myObj = Friend;
Hello myFriend = myObj; // What's wrong with this line ?
```

Comment: Image you put `myObj = 5;` before that, which you can because it's defined as `Object`. What would `Hello myFriend = 5` mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "equate two objects?"

Comment: In short, how could I modify that last line of code to  make it work ?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Hello

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672645/casting-and-dynamic-vs-static-type-in-java/2672656#2672656

Comment: @user3622264 Let's develop this question. Why do you want the last line to work ?

Comment: umm I can't really compile it because it is a question from a book that I was reading. It says "Find a way to modify that last line of code to make it work". It's a chapter on Comparable and Comparator interfaces; which I clearly do not know much about.

Comment: Right. Does Friend really have a capital F like that ? It shouldn't if it's a variable name.

Comment: What the code is doing is creating a new Hello, putting it into an Object (topmost type in Java) and then attempting to put the Object into Hello.

Comment: Question improved and voila, one more question having a chance of getting decent answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Hello Friend= new Hello("LOL");
```

Now you have variable named `Friend` of compile-time type `Hello` referring to an object of runtime type `Hello`

```
Object myObj = Friend;
```

Now you have a variable named `myObj` of compile-time type `Object` *also* referring to the same object of runtime type `Hello`. This is allowed because every `Hello` is also an  `Object`.

```
Hello myFriend = myObj; // What's wrong with this line ?
```

This fails during compilation because `myObj` has the compile-time type `Object` and you're trying to assign it to a new variable of compile-time type `Hello`. And most `Object`s are not `Hello`s. The compiler doesn't try to figure out whether this particular one is, because that is not possible in general.

But you can *force* the compiler to do it anyway by assuring you that this particular `Object`s is in fact a `Hello`:

```
Hello myFriend = (Hello) myObj;
```

This is called [casting](http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/).

Answer (score 1):

Copy from comments:

> Image you put `myObj = 5;` before that, which you can because it's defined as Object. What would `Hello myFriend = 5` mean?

The problem you get ("incompatible types") is because you are trying to assign a variable defined as `Object` (up top in the hierarchy) to a 
variable defined as `Hello` (bottom in the hierarchy). In your situation it might work but the compiler forbids this because it has no (feasible) way of knowing what happens in between or after.

This is also a valid statement:

```
Object myObj = Friend;
myObj = 5;
```

But assigning `5` to a variable of type `Hello` will obviously not work. That's why it forbids this alltogether.

You can circumvent this by explicitly casting (`Hello myFriend = (Hello) myObj;`) but this will throw a runtime exception instead if it is an impossible cast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean assign, not equate. The line fails because the operator is chosen by the compile time type. You cannot assign `Object` to `Hello` because then you could bind an instance of a class like `GoodBye` to a reference of type `Hello`.

This is possible in other languages that are not statically typed (because the types at runtime are compatible), but not in Java.

Comment: Indeed. Java is strong-typed as opposed to PHP which is weak-typed.

Comment: When casting, you have a `Hello` on both left and right-hand-side, so technically you don't assign reference to `Object` any more... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You've "erased" the type of `Friend`,

```
// The root of the Java class hierarchy is Object, that mean that 
Object myObj = Friend; // <-- (Object) can refer to anything! String, Double, Hello. :)
                       // Or, every instance of anything is-a java.lang.Object.
Hello myFriend = (Hello) myObj; // minimum
```

What you should do is something with [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496928/2970947),

```
Object myObj = Friend;
if (myObj instanceof Hello) { // <-- runtime type checking. 
  myFriend = (Hello) myObj;
}
```

or [Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) -

```
Object myObj = Friend;
if (Hello.class.isAssignableFrom(myObj)) { // <-- runtime type checking. 
  myFriend = Hello.class.cast(myObj); // <-- you can also cast with this.
}
```